# Redcarpet isn't rendering markdown inside HTML tags. Is this normal, and can it be overridden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, redcarpet

I/ve written a simple Rails helper to convert Markdown using Redcarpet. Here's the code:

```
def markdown(text)
  render_options = {
    filter_html:     false,
    hard_wrap:       true, 
    link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow' }
  }
  renderer = HTML.new(render_options)

  extensions = {
    autolink:           true,
    fenced_code_blocks: true,
    lax_spacing:        true,
    no_intra_emphasis:  true,
    strikethrough:      true,
    superscript:        true
  }
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions).render(text).html_safe
end
```

The following incoming text renders as expected, with "emphasized" in bold:

```
This is **emphasized** text.
```

However, the following text doesn't render as expected:

```
<div>
  This is **emphasized** text.
</div>
```

Everything inside the div remains unchanged. Is this normal behavior for Redcarpet/Markdown? If so, can it be overridden?
.

Comment: Try removing `html_safe` at the end

Comment: I did try that, but it escapes everything, so the resulting text is this:

`<div> This is **emphasized** text. </div>`

Comment: This is normal Markdown behavior. As the [rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state: "Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block." Some implementations allow you to override that rule, but I don't see such an option for Redcarpet. Perhaps someone more familiar with Redcarpet can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported as [Redcarpet issue #13](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/issues/13), and the suggestion of the developers there has been up to now to use a Markdown processor that supports this "non-standard" extension of Markdown, for example [Kramdown](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown):

> If you're looking for a Markdown processor with an extension that will parse Markdown inside an HTML block, I highly suggest looking at another markdown processor, such as Kramdown, which does allow this sort of mixing. ([source](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/issues/13#issuecomment-35351105))

If you want to go down that route, you'd use Kramdown like this:

```
require 'kramdown'

text = "<div>Wow! Markdown _inside_ HTML!</div>"
options = { input: "Kramdown", parse_block_html: true }
Kramdown::Document.new(text, options).to_html
```

For official documentation about the `parse_block_html` option, [see here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/rdoc/Kramdown/Options.html).